# BroadcastReceiver on Application.onCreate()

Tags: android-intent, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, android

I am trying to do a widget, that will react to `ACTION_SCREEN_ON/_OFF`. I attempted to declare the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, but it didn't work. Somewhere I read that it should be registered in code. I Wrote:

```
    public class TimeTableApp extends Application {

    public void OnCreate() {
       Log.d("FinWi","appOncreate");
       Context cnt = this.getApplicationContext();
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
       intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
       intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
       BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenStateBroadcastReceiver();
       cnt.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
       super.onCreate();
    }
  }
```

---

```
    <application android:name=".TimeTableApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <receiver android:name=".TimeTableWidgetProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_provider" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

    </application>`
```

It does not call `onCreate()`.

Comment: onCreate()....   but was OnCreate()...

Comment: everything else works OK

Comment: you were not actually overriding oncreate as it takes BUndle as parameter ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact code you've been trying, then problem is that you have it all wrong with onCreate method. 
This is how it should look like (there should be @Override, and onCreate starts with "o" instead of "O", ):

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
           .
           .
           .
```